# OctoberCMS | How to get dropdown value in php (ajax)

Tags: octobercms

I need to get the selected element of the dropdown, in php.
October [1] uses the alias input('value') to get value submitted in the `form` , and it works fine for the `input` tag, but I'm not sure how do I get the value of the `dropdown`?

Many thanks

[1] https://octobercms.com/docs/ajax/introduction

**HTML**

```
<form data-request="onTest"  >

    <input name="value1">  <!-- this works fine -->

    <select class="form-control" id="idtitle" name="idtitle">
         <option selected disabled hidden>{{default}} </option>  
         <option>Ms</option>
         <option>Mrs</option>
         <option>Mr</option>
         <option>None</option>         
       </select>

    <!-- Action button -->
    <button type="submit">Calculate</button>

</form>
```

**PHP**

```
function onTest()
{
    $var= input('value1')  ;  // OK
    $dropdown=input('idtitle'); // NULL
    $dropdown= $_GET['idtitle']; // NULL
}
```

Comment: I use `\Input::post('idtitle')` and I always get the dropdown value

Comment: Thank you Zakir, it worked. How do I mark this as resolved?

Comment: I am glad it's worked for you. you can mark as resolve on my answer below. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

use `\Input::post('idtitle')` and it will work !!!

Answer (score 0):

Besides `\Input::post()` you can get inputs with `Input::get('idtitle')` or `Input::all()`. Just make sure to have `use Input;` declaration if this is in a plugin class file (component.php or class.php).

Also in my testing `input('idtitle')` did work for me.

I think why `$_GET` doesn't is because this is an ajax post not a typical form post.